# angular cannot get data from backend to frontend

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get data to the angular frontend. Tried to get data from another api, but still doesnt worked for me. So the API is working but the data cant displayed on the frontend. I read the docs but it doesn't helped to fix the problem. Hope anyone can help me.

**Employee Class:**

```
export class Employee {
id!: number;
firstName!: string;
lastName!: string;
emailId!: string;
}
```

**Employee-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../employee';
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  employees!: Employee[];

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployees();
  }

  private getEmployees(){
    this.employeeService.getEmployeesList().subscribe(data =>{
      this.employees = data;
    });
  }

}
```

**Employee-list.component.html**

```
<h2> Mitarbeiter Liste</h2>
<table class = "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Vorname</th>
            <th> Nachname</th>
            <th> Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
            <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.emailId }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Employee.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Employee } from './employee';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployeesList(): Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**The API data:**

> [{"id":1,"firstName":"Frank","lastName":"wettew","emailId":"test@gmail.de"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Herbert","lastName":"Hubert","emailId":"herb@gmail.de"}]
> ^

**Frontend**:
[image]

Comment: What is the error message that you are seeing?

Comment: there is no error message. I want to display the 2 employees on my angular frontend, but they are not displayed. I edited a image of my frontend to the post. Thanks!

Comment: You've maybe checked this but for the sake of ruling it out, is your backend running? If you do a console.log() in your subscription in the getEmployees() method does it log out the data you are expecting?

Comment: Thank your for that. Thats true i dont geht the data out of the backend. The error message i get is: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: i now solved the problem. Thank your for that advice! I need to add to my controller @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i now solved the problem. Thank your for that advice! I need to add to my controller @CrossOrigin(origins = "localhost:4200")

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your Angular frontend and it works fine.

So my assumption is there is error with fetching data from backend.

Check in browser in network tab if "employees" request was successful.

Comment: Whilst this is helpful it is better suited as a comment as it doesn't seek to answer the question